# Hibernate Many to one bidirectional using generics

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity class which I need to use at multiple places. So I created a class with generics as below

```
class Output<T> {
    ...
    private String referencedEntityName; 
    private T referencedEntity; 
    ...

}
```

I've two other classes which are using this class

```
class Process {
     ...
     private List<Output<Process>> outputs;
     ...
}
```

Another class which uses `Output<T>` is

```
class Machine {
    ...
    private List<Output<Machine>> outputs; 
    ...

}
```

When stored in database it should look like this

```
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
| id | referenced_entity_name | referenced_entity_id |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
| 1  | Process                | 123                  |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
| 2  | Process                | 234                  |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
| 3  | Machine                | 345                  |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
```

How do I achieve this?

P. S. This is not exactly an inheritance problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772370/when-to-use-discriminatorvalue-annotation-in-hibernate). Though it could be solved using an interface solution like `DiscriminatorValue` but I'm not sure.

Here, there is a relation between two entities, one entity is referred in a few other entities. I think that should be clear by the use of generics. 
Also, this solution could be designed in some other way by maintaining the same relations. I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use DiscriminatorValue annotation in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772370/when-to-use-discriminatorvalue-annotation-in-hibernate)

Comment: please make question clear , not understandable title , many to one bidirectional  ?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think it's not duplicate. I'm not using inheritance here. I'm using relation with generics

Comment: @MithatKonuk Yes. Many to one bidirectional relationship with generics

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937644/generics-with-hibernate/35938380) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000428/using-hibernate-with-generics). 2 more questions which already deal with generics in hibernate. It definitly looks like you need `@Any` relationship

Answer (score 1):

Read about inheritance in JPA. With inheritance strategy SINGLE_TABLE you will get ***exactly table like you posted***. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_single_table_inheritance_table_in_database

Comment: I think it's not an inheritance problem. I'm trying to use generics so that I could use this code efficiently.